# Why I am getting "cannot have two @Spatial using default/same name"

Tags: hibernate, search, spatial, hibernate-search

I am definitelly using one @Spatial, but getting this err "HSEARCH000158: Class core.model.User cannot have two @Spatial using default/same name" why?

I am using one spatial in one entity, why it is happining? Can not I use spatial in two different entity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot have two @Spatial using default/same name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43235186/cannot-have-two-spatial-using-default-same-name)

Comment: no, I use only one Spatial in one Entity. Totally I have two different Entiity